# Why does lld-link say that the symbol "__memset_nt_iters" is undefined when cross-compiling from Linux to Windows?

Tags: c++, clang, llvm, cross-compiling

I am trying to use clang to cross-compile to Windows on Linux. I think that I need to get the standard library stuff from elsewhere, so I used -v when compiling on Windows to see what Windows clang was using, and then copied those files to Linux. Right now I am compiling using a script that looks something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
clang++ -fuse-ld=lld -target x86_64-pc-windows-msvc \
-I /home/.../include/clang \
-I /home/.../include/msvc \
-I /home/.../include/atlmfc \
-I /home/.../include/ucrt \
-I /home/.../include/shared \
-I /home/.../include/um \
-I /home/.../include/winrt \
-L /home/.../lib/msvc \
-L /home/.../lib/atlmfc \
-L /home/.../lib/ucrt \
-L /home/.../lib/um \
-L /home/.../lib/clang \
$@
```

This is the test program that I am trying to compile:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    return argc;
}
```

At first, I ran into an issue where some libraries (kernel32.Lib and Uuid.Lib) couldn't be found, but it seemed to arise from case-sensitivity, so this was easily fixed using two all-lowercase symlinks.

But now lld-link is complaining about how "__memset_nt_iters" is undefined, and I have no idea what this is about. Look at the verbose output:

```
clang version 10.0.0-4ubuntu1 
Target: x86_64-pc-windows-msvc
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /usr/bin
 "/usr/lib/llvm-10/bin/clang" -cc1 -triple x86_64-pc-windows-msvc19.11.0 -emit-obj -mrelax-all -mincremental-linker-compatible -disable-free -disable-llvm-verifier -discard-value-names -main-file-name ret.cpp -mrelocation-model pic -pic-level 2 -mthread-model posix -mframe-pointer=none -fmath-errno -fno-rounding-math -masm-verbose -mconstructor-aliases -munwind-tables -target-cpu x86-64 -dwarf-column-info -v -resource-dir /usr/lib/llvm-10/lib/clang/10.0.0 -I /home/.../include/clang -I /home/.../include/msvc -I /home/.../include/atlmfc -I /home/.../include/ucrt -I /home/.../include/shared -I /home/.../include/um -I /home/.../include/winrt -internal-isystem /usr/lib/llvm-10/lib/clang/10.0.0/include -fdeprecated-macro -fdebug-compilation-dir /home/... -ferror-limit 19 -fmessage-length 0 -fno-use-cxa-atexit -fms-extensions -fms-compatibility -fms-compatibility-version=19.11 -std=c++14 -fdelayed-template-parsing -fobjc-runtime=gcc -fcxx-exceptions -fexceptions -fdiagnostics-show-option -fcolor-diagnostics -faddrsig -o /tmp/ret-004e99.o -x c++ ret.cpp
clang -cc1 version 10.0.0 based upon LLVM 10.0.0 default target x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /home/.../include/clang
 /home/.../include/msvc
 /home/.../include/atlmfc
 /home/.../include/ucrt
 /home/.../include/shared
 /home/.../include/um
 /home/.../include/winrt
 /usr/lib/llvm-10/lib/clang/10.0.0/include
End of search list.
 "/usr/lib/llvm-10/bin/lld-link" -out:ret.exe -libpath:lib/amd64 -libpath:atlmfc/lib/amd64 -libpath:/home/.../lib/msvc -libpath:/home/.../lib/atlmfc -libpath:/home/.../lib/ucrt -libpath:/home/.../lib/um -libpath:/home/.../lib/clang -nologo /tmp/ret-004e99.o libcmt.lib
lld-link: error: undefined symbol: __memset_nt_iters
>>> referenced by D:\a01\_work\9\s\src\vctools\crt\vcruntime\src\string\amd64\memset.asm:134
>>>               libvcruntime.lib(memset.obj):(XmmSetLarge)
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: Libraries [description page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/crt-library-features?view=msvc-160) says: `If you link your program from the command line without a compiler option that specifies a C runtime library, the linker will use the statically linked CRT libraries: libcmt.lib, libvcruntime.lib, and libucrt.lib.`. So, you probably need to link all these 3 libraries too.

Comment: @dewaffled `wincc -v libcmt.lib libucrt.lib libvcruntime.lib ret.cpp -o ret.exe` and `wincc -v ret.cpp -o ret.exe -llibcmt.lib -llibucrt.lib -llibvcruntime.lib` give the same problem, `wincc -v ret.cpp -o ret.exe -llibcmt -llibucrt -lvcruntime` causes it to say `lld-link: error: duplicate symbol: __vcrt_InitializeCriticalSectionEx` (I have the files copied in the same directory)

Answer (score 0):

I have now managed to get it to compile. What I did was add the arguments `-Xlinker /force`, which make the linker ignore the fact that there's an undefined symbol and continue anyway. The resulting executable (from compiling the test program) seems to run fine, at least in Wine.

What's interesting is that when I compiled a larger project the error (now warning) about "__memset_nt_iters" went away. I have not been able to isolate what solved the issue in that case.